# Laravel Homestead and Nginx subdomain wildcard

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, dns, homestead

i have problem with nginx and homestead. I can't make dynamic subdomain working. I tried everything here is my configuration.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit

Guest OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit ( Vagrant with Homestead )

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 512
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /home/user/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: businesspage.local
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/BusinessPage/public
```

/etc/hosts

```
192.168.10.10   businesspage.local
192.168.10.10   *.businesspage.local
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/businesspage.local

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name businesspage.local *.businesspage.local;
    root "/home/vagrant/Projects/BusinessPage/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

And finally this is what i added in dnsmasq.conf

```
address=/.local/192.168.10.10
```

Also I added 192.168.10.10 as additional DNS server in my host network configuration. I also flashed the dns, reboot etc... I don't know what else i can do. When i try to open http://businesspage.local it works, but if i try to open http://en.businesspage.local it's not working. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** For those who have the same problem, Never use .local TLD. This was my problem. .local is used by samba or something else... You should use .dev or something else but not .local !!!

Comment: try address=/businesspage.local/192.168.10.10 in dnsmasq.conf

Comment: Nope... It's not working. After i made the changes i restarted the dnsmasq service.

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Comment: @Citizen look at the update of my op also dont use. .dev use. ".test"