# laravel 5.2, wildcard subdomains

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, wildcard-subdomain

I want to have routes like this:

```
john-doe.mysite.local
john-another-doe.mysite.local
```

and then pass the subdomain name to some controller@method and present the users profiles.

I'm using [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead).

Here's my `/etc/hosts` file from my local machine:

```
....
192.168.10.10 mysite.local
192.168.10.10 *.mysite.local
....
```

and on my virtual machine the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.local` file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.local *.mysite.local;
    root "/home/vagrant/laravel-projects/mysite.com/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    ....
```

If you need anything else please ask.
The main domain `mysite.local` works normally.

I tried following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) an adding this to my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.mysite.local'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function ($element) {
        dd($element);
    });

});
```

But if I go to any subdomain `somedomain.mysite.local` I get server not found.

It seems to me the problem is that I'm not even reaching Laravel app through the subdomain.

Any help is appreciated. 
I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696725/laravel-homestead-and-nginx-subdomain-wildcard), and tried changing `.local` to `.dev` in my `/etc/hosts` and `mysite.local` files but it didn't work. I also tried changing `mysite.local` to `mysite.dev` but it didn't work either.

I can't figure out what am I missing here.

**UPDATE:**

If I add `test.mysite.local` to my `/etc/hosts` file I get the same output in my browser as if I was to browse for `mysite.local`.

```
....
192.168.10.10 mysite.local
192.168.10.10 test.mysite.local
192.168.10.10 *.mysite.local
....
```

Updating the `mysite.local` on virtual machine:

```
...
server_name mysite.local test.mysite.local *.mysite.local;
...
```

I tried adding another route to `routes.php`:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'test.mysite.local'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        dd('you are at test subdomain');
    });

});
```

to see if it works but it doesn't, I still get the same output as if I were to navigate to `mysite.local`

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

`/etc/hosts/` doesn't support wildcards so for the moment I'm using static subdomain names and will figure out how to do dynamic subdomains a bit later.

Also put

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.mysite.local'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function ($element) {
        dd($element);
    });

});
```

**AT THE TOP** or your `routes.php` file.

At the moment I'm trying to redirect static subdomain to the specific controller@method. Will update this as I progress.

**UPDATE - static domain working now:**

New route:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{element}.mysite.local'], function() {

    Route::get('{path}', 'ElementController@single')->where('path', '.*');

});
```

`ElementController.php`

```
public function single($element)
{
    //return view with information about my element
    if ( $element = Element::where('slug', $element)->first() )
    {
        return view('elements.single', compact('element'));
    }

    //redirect to mysite.local if slug doesn't exist
    return redirect(Config::get('app.url')); // points to config/app.php and find `url` parameter which should be defined in your `.env` file

}
```

**TODO:**

- `slug.mysite.local/sadsadas` works and runs the `single` method from above, I
  would prefer if it would redirect to `slug.mysite.local`
- wildcard subdomains still not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?
168.168.10.10 in your hosts.... it seems have to be 192.168.10.10

Comment: Nothing, but now I need to try again with changing the `.local` to `.dev` because I'm not sure when did this typo occur. Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing the `.local` to `.dev` in `hosts` and `mysite.local` files. Also I copied `mysite.local` to `mysite.dev` but it didn't work. However, this brought another problem and that is when I opened `mysite.dev` in my browser I got presented with another site I have locally that is also defined in my `hosts` file. It redirected to it even if I commented it in the `hosts` file. It seems I'm missing something big here.

Comment: can you confirm that the nginx configuration already working well? i mean try to use simple domain without subdomain first and then simple routes in laravel.. see if the page is opened or not

Comment: Yes, the TLD is working well. It's just the subdomains I can't reach.

Comment: I updated the `/etc/hosts` with `192.168.10.10 test.mysite.local` and when I point to it with my browser I get same response as if I was to go to `mysite.local`.